# Can`t set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I`m trying to find an error in my code, and nothing from other topics fits.

There is app.js code, which contains `get` method from Express module:

```
app.get('/notes', notesController.all);
```

There is notesController.js code, which exports to app.js `create` method:

```
exports.all = function (req, res) {
    Notes.all(function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        res.send(docs);
    })
};
```

In `model` this code:

```
exports.all = function (cb) {
    db.get().collection('notes').find().toArray(function (err, docs) {
        cb(err,docs);
    })
};
```

App crashes with this error:

> ```
> process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>                               ^
> ```
>
> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (O:\OGPI6\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:725:10)
>       at ServerResponse.json (O:\OGPI6\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:253:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (O:\OGPI6\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
>       at O:\OGPI6\controllers\notes.js:9:13
>       at O:\OGPI6\models\notes.js:6:9
>       at handleCallback (O:\OGPI6\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
>       at O:\OGPI6\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:860:16
>       at handleCallback (O:\OGPI6\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:171:5)
>       at setCursorDeadAndNotified (O:\OGPI6\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:505:3)

At my mind only error with "controller" in the callback function:

```
if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        res.send(docs);
```

But I thought that when an error occurs it must terminate function and return `sendStatus(500)`, but after logging an error in the console it tries to return `res.send(docs)` and then the app crashes because it is sending the second header. It looks fine but doesn`t work. Can anyone point which way I have failed?

Comment: Do you think that yout `exports.all` method might be firing off the call back multiple times. Have you tried to put a `console.log` at the beginning of the callback?

Comment: I agree with @BenjiLees, it looks like the callback is getting called twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "next" parameter in the middleware to make express know that the purpose of this middleware is completed and there is no further need to execute the code.

```
exports.all = function (req, res, next) {
    Notes.all(function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return next();
        }
        res.send(docs);
    })
};
```

Execution of code after return maybe due to the async nature.

You can also use else block.

```
exports.all = function (req, res, next) {
        Notes.all(function(err, docs){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(500);

            }
            else res.send(docs);
        })
    };
```

Comment: Both sending back a response _and_ calling `next` is not a good idea, because `next` may make Express pass control to another request handler (or a final "not found" handler) that may also send back a response.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
if(err){
  console.log(err);
  return res.status(500).send(err);
}
res.send(docs);
```